# Symbolically solving a complicated trigonometric equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I want to solve a trigonometric equation involving a few `sine` functions, for an argument of `sine` function. 
The equation in its simplest form is 
$$-\sin(3k+\phi)+\alpha\sin(2k+\phi)+\beta\sin^2k\sin(2k+\phi)=0$$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ constants and $k$ is a variable (a number between $-\pi$ to $\pi$), and I want to solve it for $\phi$. I tried with `Solve`

```
 Solve[-Sin[3*k + φ] + α*
 Sin[2*k + φ] + β*(Sin^2)[k]*
 Sin[2*k + φ] == 0, φ]
```

I get a long output, also with an error message

```
Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
```

How do I get a correct output? which is simplified a bit?

Comment: `FullSimplify@Solve[-Sin[3*k + φ] + α* Sin[2*k + φ] + β*(Sin^2)[k]* Sin[2*k + φ] == 0, φ]` (wrapped in `Quiet` if you want to suppress the warning message) does give a reasonably simplified result.

Comment: Thanks. How do I put in the condition on $k$ that $-\pi\leq k\leq\pi$? It may simplify the answer a bit further?

Comment: `Solve[-Sin[3*k+φ]+α*Sin[2*k+φ]+β*(Sin^2)[k]*Sin[2*k+φ]==0//TrigExpand,φ]//Simplify` or 
`Solve[-Sin[3*k+φ]+α*Sin[2*k+φ]+β*(Sin^2)[k]*Sin[2*k+φ]==0/.φ->ArcTan[x]//TrigExpand,x]//Simplify`

Comment: AtoZ, you can use the option `Assumptions -> {-Pi <= k <= Pi}` in `FullSimplify` but, in this case, it does not change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the "tangent half angle substitution" you force the constraint `-Pi<k <Pi, -Pi<\[CurlyPhi]<Pi`

```
eq = (-Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + \[Alpha]*Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + \[Beta]*(Sin^2)[k]*Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] 
/. {k -> 2 ArcTan[uk], \[CurlyPhi] ->2 ArcTan[u\[CurlyPhi]]} // TrigExpand  ) /.  (Sin^2)[2 ArcTan[uk]] -> (TrigExpand[Sin[2 ArcTan[uk]]])^2 // Simplify
```

Now the equation is rational in `uk, u\[CurlyPhi]`  and can be solved without warning and ConditionalExpression

```
Solve[eq == 0 , u\[CurlyPhi]] /. {u\[CurlyPhi] -> Tan[\[CurlyPhi]/2],uk -> Tan[k/2]} //Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There is a twin equation I am trying to solve which seems slightly harder `Solve[-Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/
   Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + \[Alpha] + (\[Mu]*(Sin^2)[
     k])/((Sin^2)[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + \[Beta]*(Sin^2)[k]) == 
  0, \[CurlyPhi]]`, `solve` is unable to handle it. Any suggestion on this one?

Comment: My solution with this new equation works, but the solution  contains Root-objects.

Comment: Root objects? Do we get the solution(s)  `\[CurlyPhi]` somehow? Can you please show the code so I can put it and try to run. Thanks

Comment: `(-Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/
       Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + \[Alpha] + (\[Mu]*Sin[k]^2)/( 
        Sin [2*k + \[CurlyPhi]]^2 + \[Beta]*Sin[k]^2) /. {k -> 
       2 ArcTan[uk], \[CurlyPhi] -> 2 ArcTan[u\[CurlyPhi]]} // 
    TrigExpand  ) /.  (Sin^2)[
    2 ArcTan[uk]] -> (TrigExpand[Sin[2 ArcTan[uk]]])^2 // Simplify`
`Solve[% == 0, u\[CurlyPhi]]`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get atleast a truncated solution? its too long even `FullSimplify` doesn't get it enough straightened up.

Comment: What means "truncated solution"? The analytical solution can only be simplified for given parametervalues `\[Alpha], \[Beta]` and/or additional information about the parameters.

Comment: Correct, thanks. I will try myself and if not successful, then will create a question with more information in it regarding the parameters.