# Numerical solution of complicated trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, symbolic

I have the following equation to numerically solve for `\[CurlyPhi]` as function of $k$ and $x$. $k$ is normally between $-\pi\leq k\leq\pi$.

```
   A = 0.5;
   B = 0.1;
   P = -2.5;
Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] == 
P + 2 Cos[k] + x^2/(1 + B*x^2) + (
A*x^2*(Sin^2)[k])/((Sin^2)[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + B*x^2*(Sin^2)[k])
```

Since this is analytically not solvable, so I started with lim $x\to 0$, and the solution is found in this limit, but then I want to see how numerical solutions `\[CurlyPhi]` would change with increasing $x$. So either directly numerical solution or this way is OK but I don't understand how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The solution is done in the same way you asked for in **your** question "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180484/symbolically-solving-a-complicated-trigonometric-equation/180495#180495"

Comment: I couldn't understand what's `u` there? Secondly, the output is too long even after providing the parameters as above with several (...1....)^n which i dont know what they mean. Lastly, that was a numerical solution?

Comment: If you show your own efforts it is easier to support you and less time consuming...

Comment: This `(Sin^2)[k]` is a syntax error. In Mma it is `Sin[k]^2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the equation as

```
eq[\[CurlyPhi]_, k_, x_] := Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] == 
P + 2 Cos[k] +x^2/(1 + B*x^2) + (A*x^2* Sin [k]^2)/(Sin  [2*k + \[CurlyPhi]]^2 + B*x^2*Sin [k]^2) /. {A -> 1/2,B -> 1/10, P -> -25/10}
```

Contourplot shows you the numerical solutions for variing x:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot [Evaluate[eq[\[CurlyPhi], k, x]] , {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {k, -Pi,Pi}, FrameLabel -> {\[CurlyPhi], k}], {{x, 1}, 0, 3, .01,Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

The several solutions can be evaluated with

```
phi[x_?NumericQ, k_ /; -Pi <= k <= Pi] := \[CurlyPhi] /. 
NSolve[{eq[\[CurlyPhi], k, x],0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 2 Pi}, \[CurlyPhi], Reals]
phi[1, 3]
(* {0.193985, 3.33558}*)
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you get this output? the code shows a different 3D output?

Comment: Now it should work (hopefully)

Comment: I get the output but the appearance is not the same as yours. I use MMA 11.3. Mine is showing `CountourPlot` for funtion, not the equation.?

Comment: Possible, but what is the different appearance? My MMA version is 11.0.1

Comment: I have added my output in the question, just to show you.

Comment: What's your input? Did you change `Sin^2[...]`?

Comment: Yes I simply copy pasted your code and started with a clean kernel. One question: `{0.193985, 3.33558}` are the numerical values of `\[CurlyPhi]`?

Comment: No idea, try Option `MaxRecursion->` inside ContourPlot.

Comment: Ok I think I fixed it I simply placed `==0` here,  `...B*x^2*Sin[k]^2) == 0 /. {A -> 1/2...` Now I get the output as yours.

Comment: So you didn't used my definition of `eq[...]` which already contains `==`...

Comment: thats what I wonder because your definition already contains it, but I don't understand somehow placing ``==0` there gives me the output as yours? just followed the documentation where countrouplots for functions and for equations looked differed so I thought to just try and see.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if  you would show ultimatly your input(effort)...

Comment: I didn't change anything in your code except placing a `==0` there. I used your code to get the output. I think it has to do with the different MMA versions we are using and nothing else.

Comment: So please just copy the two input lines you used in the comment , so that I can check it...

Comment: There you go: `eq[\[CurlyPhi]_, k_, 
  T_] := -Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] + P + 
    2 Cos[k] + 
    T^2/(1 + B*T^2) + (A*T^2*Sin[k]^2)/(Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]]^2 + 
       B*T^2*Sin[k]^2) == 0 /. {A -> 1/2, B -> 1/10, P -> -25/10}`

Comment: Bingo: That's not the definition of eq in my answer...

Comment: You mean I did the correct thing there by adding `==0` in your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
A = 1/2;
B = 1/10;
P = -5/2;

phi[k_, x_, p0_] := \[CurlyPhi] /. 
  FindRoot[Sin[3*k + \[CurlyPhi]]/
      Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]] - (P + 2 Cos[k] + x^2/(1 + B*x^2) + 
       A*x^2*Sin[k]^2/(Sin[2*k + \[CurlyPhi]]^2 + B*x^2*Sin[k]^2)) == 
    0, {\[CurlyPhi], p0}]
Plot3D[phi[k, x, 1], {k, -Pi, Pi}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: fig1]